# Limit users to one game per device on android/ios app

Tags: android, ios, google-play, game-center

I understand how to sign in to google play/ game center. I would like to know how to go about letting players transfer their accounts between devices. Exactly the way games like clash of clans do. If anyone has insight on this or could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clash of Clans lets users transfer/share accounts on multiple devices with their own mechanism outside of Google Play and Game Center.

When you go to link a device, their game server generates a temporary access token that they associate with your online-stored game account and give you that access token string. When you go to another device and activate that access token by entering in the same string, they attribute the installation on that device with the same user account.

I'm not sure why this question is getting down voted.. perhaps it's just improperly tagged. Also, a more accurate title would be 'Allow users to use multiple devices...' not 'Limit users...'

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what i want to do! i just want to make sure multiple accounts can't be used on one device

Comment: Well, just don't let them add an account on a device that already has an active account. Or when they add a new account, remove the old one. That's entirely up to how you want to store your local account authentication information.

Comment: That sounds perfect as long as they can't redownload the app and sign in again to a different account.

Comment: And what's wrong with that? If I buy a used device, for example, it would be a shame to not be able to play a game because someone else played it once.

Comment: True. What do you think is a good way to prevent players from making multiple accounts then and gaining an unfair advantage?

Comment: I think we're getting into the game design territory more than programming. I would recommend checking out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design. But IMHO in short, make sure new players can't give as much help as seasoned players. If people want to make/play/switch between multiple accounts, it sounds like they are really engaged and keeping the balance is your job and maybe account juggling is a feature you might want to adopt. Good problems to have, if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer high scores, achievements, etc., they will automatically transfer when using something like Game Center as long as the user signs in with the same account on both devices.

However, if you want the actual *game content* to transfer between devices, that gets a little more complicated. Normally, people will set up a server (using something like [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) - free for the first year and very reliable) and store game data there. That way, the user can create an account on your game server, your game can upload game saves to the server, and when the user signs in on another device, you can have the game automatically download the game content from your server to the new device.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Play Saved Games API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) allows you to store up to 3MB of data and keep it synchronized across both Android and iOS devices:

> The Saved Games service makes it possible to synchronize a player's game data across multiple devices. For example, if you have a game that runs on Android, you can use the Saved Games service to allow a player to start a game on their Android phone, and then continue playing on a tablet without losing any of their progress. This service can also be used to ensure that a player's game play continues from where it left off even if their device is lost, destroyed, or traded in for a newer model.